# Approximating polynomial under monotonicity constraint

Tags: polynomials, approximation

Given a bivariate data set, how does one obtain the most accurate least-squares polynomial approximation under the constraint that the resulting polynomial is non-decreasing. Similarly, how does one proceed with a trivariate data set with the same constraint applying to the resulting bivariate polynomial.

Comment: Is it a Mathematica question? Looks like it is a general mathematical problem. Can you provide an example of such data and indicate why least square fit is unsatisfactory.

Comment: Yet another point, the polynomial should be non-descreasing in what direction?